# Using "with" in object literal?

Tags: javascript

Isn't it possible to do use something like "with" in javascript - like...

```
var test = {
    vars: {
        customer: {
            Name: '',
            Address: '',
            Town: ''
        }
    },

    Init: function () {
        with this.vars.customer {
            Name = 'Mike';
            Address = 'Union Square 2';
            Town = 'San Francisco'; 
        }       
    }
}
```

?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I don't like this syntax:

```
Init: function () {
            this.vars.customer.Name = 'Mike';
            this.vars.customer.Address = 'Union Square 2';
            this.vars.customer.Town = 'San Francisco'; 
        }
```

It's quite messy

Comment: possible, but not recommended.  At least mozilla doesn't recommend it.

Comment: why do you want to do it?

Comment: What is your question? Are you not sure about the syntax?

Comment: recommended best practice is to avoid using the `with` keyword entirely. It introduces syntax ambiguities that can be really hard to catch.

Comment: I've updated my question .. sry for not being clear - thx guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.vars.customer = {
   Name: 'Mike';
   Address: 'Union Square 2';
   Town: 'San Francisco'; 
}
```

If it is about settings properties, maybe you can do something like this. It far from a `with` replacement, but it may have it's uses, and it's less ambigous than `with`.

```
function mergeObject(obj, into){
    for (var key in obj){
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            into[key] = obj[key];
        }
    }
}

var o = {test: 'Hello', test2: 'world'};
// Add/set properties to o.
mergeObject({foo: 'foo', bar: 'FOO'}, o);


alert(o.test + o.foo);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a2BTY/

Comment: That will create a new object, not just change properties of the existing object. It won't be the same if references to the existing object are being held somewhere or there are properties of the existing object you're not setting here.

Comment: You're right, Gabe. That's something to keep in mind. And strictly speaking that means that the actual answer to the question is 'no'. :)

Comment: @Esailija Did I say no? I meant 'yes'. ;)

Comment: I really see no problem with `with`. MDN says "not recommended" but if you can be careful with it, I don't see the harm in using it.

Answer (score 0):

[The "with" keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) IS in JavaScript.

Not recommended as it can create ambiguous variable scopes if not careful.  I think the other answers given here are better JS coding practices

example usage

```
x = { subObj: {a: 100, b: 200} };

with (x.subObj) { 
   console.log(a); // should show 100
   b = "what";  // should assign x.subObj.b to be "what now"
}
```